# Can't perform terraform apply -target

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm new to Terraform and I can't perform apply to a target.

Data Structure;

```
  |----- main.tf
  |
  |----- modules |----- compute_engine_lb |----- !compute_engine_lb_backup.tf
                                          |----- other files.......
```

On main.tf I have;

```
   module "compute_engine_lb" {
         source = "./modules/compute_engine_lb"
         .... some vars .....
   }
```

On !compute_engine_lb_backup.tf I have;

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "lb_backup" {
    count = var.count_lb_backup
    name = "lb-backup-${count.index + 1}"
    .... rest of resource......
}
```

This resource creates x instances defined by a var.tf file.

I want to apply just for this resource so I did;

`terraform apply -auto-approve  -target=module.compute_engine_lb.google_compute_instance.lb_backup`

It gives me this error;

```
│ Error: Invalid target "module"
│
│ Prefix "module." must be followed by a module name.
```

I would appreciate the help

Comment: I think you want `-auto-approve` at the end of the command, i.e., `terraform apply -target=module.compute_engine_lb.google_compute_instance.lb_backup -auto-approve`.

Comment: Hi again Marko, I figured it out and I'm going to answer my own question just have to wait it out, so apparently some local shells might have an issue parsing the target=..., so you just need to put it on a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue in your local Shell environment trying to parse the target string.

Doing `-target='module.compute_engine_lb.google_compute_instance.lb_backup'`
works